# How to parse this html page using mechanize (ruby gem)? *small amendment*

Tags: ruby, parsing, html, nokogiri

On the page I have the following HTML source:

```
<div class="date">date1</div>

<div class="company"><div class="time">time1</div>
<a href="company_link1">company_name1</a></div>

<div class="company"><div class="time">time2</div>
<a href="company_link2">company_name2</a></div>

<div class="date">date2</div>
<div class="company"><div class="time">time3</div>
<a href="company_link3">company_name3</a></div>

... etc.
```

I need to receive at final stage the following array:

> array = [ [date, time1, company_name1, company_link1], [date, time2, company_name2, company_link2], [date2, time3, company_name3, company_link3], ... ]

The problem is that div "class=company" doesn't have the date, so I need to parse the correct dates and add each date to all items (time, company name, company link).

Thanks a lot for your help, I'm a newbie to Ruby.

PS: I need to use mechanize cause my page can be retrieved only via log-in.

Comment: I've tried  to use the following code:

`cv_views = agent.get ('http://some_page')
list_of_companies = cv_views.search("//div[@class='b-resumehistory-company']").collect {|span| span.inner_text}`

But this info is not useful without correct dates...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, your date2 div isn't closed properly but maybe something like:

```
doc.css('.company').map{|x| [x.at('./preceding-sibling::div[@class="date"][1]').text, x.at('.time').text, x.at('a').text, x.at('a')[:href]]}
```

Comment: +1 This mix of CSS selector and XPath leads to a very concise solution, isn't Nokogiri great? (One question: do you need the [1] in your preceding-sibling clause since you're using 'at'?)

Comment: ah thanks for the nice compliment @Mark Thomas. Yes I believe the [1] will indicate the first in terms of proximity to the element rather than first in terms of parent index.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the object doc? (cause I've tried to use method css for Mechanize.object - no sucess.

PS: I've corrected date closing tag. Thanks.

Comment: Damn, it was my mistake) this page I can get only using mechanize cause the user must be loged-in. Any other options? pguardiario

Comment: In that case it would be doc.parser

Comment: pguardiario, can you please prepare the request to mechanize method? (doc.parser)

Comment: @jagga99 Mechanize exposes Nokogiri in the `search()` method of `Mechanize::Page`. So you would need to use `doc.search('.company').map...` instead.